# (Python) Программа для поиска палиндромных чисел среди заданного диапазона

Tags: python

Всем привет, нужна программа на питоне, с помощью которой собственно сам код будет искать палиндромные числа. Например найти числа от 100 до 1000000.

Answer (score 3):

1. пройти в цикле от 100 до 1000000 (через `range`)
2. превратить число в строку (через `str`)
3. превратить строку в перевернутую (через `[::-1]`)
4. сравнить строки и если совпадают - число - палиндром

**P.S.**

> Всем привет, нужна программа на питоне

Всем привет, нужны деньги, счет банка XXXX-XXXX-XXXX

**P.P.S.**

Попробуйте хотя бы первые 5 страниц учебника по питону прочитать - куча задач будет решена

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ